# Need better understanding of my problem about SEEK_HOLE

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix

This might be look like a duplicate read, but it's not.
My problem is that I am trying to copy a file containing hole to other file, that should contain all the data from the previous file; but the hole. (an assignment from apue)
Though there are 2 questions about it on this forum, none caters to my need.
Problem:
Hole is not being read, but instead, LSEEK with SEEK_HOLE seems to point to "end of hole".
Here's the file with hole:

```
$ od -c file.hole
0000000   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
*
0001740  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \n   A   B   C   D   E   G   H
0001760   I   J  \n
0001763

$ ls -ls file.hole
4 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 smb smb 1011 Nov 22 14:35 file.hole
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int
main (void)
{
    int fd_in   = open ("file.hole", O_RDONLY);
    int fd_out  = open ("file.nohole", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0755);

    if (fd_in < 0)
    {
        perror ("open (infile)");
        exit (1);
    }
    if (fd_out < 0)
    {
        perror ("open (outfile)");
        exit (1);
    }

    off_t data = lseek (fd_in, 0, SEEK_DATA);
    off_t hole = 0;
    if (data < 0)
    {
        // no data in file or lseek error

    }
    else
    {
        // data found , either at the beginning or somewhere
        // find the next hole from data's offset
        hole = lseek (fd_in, data, SEEK_HOLE);
        if (hole != -1)
        {
            printf ("%llu bytes to read\n", hole - data);
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
./mycp.out
1011 bytes to read
```

Also, while does the file contain 1011 bytes?
I have created it as -- "abcdefghij(hole of 1000 bytes)\nABCDEFGHIJ". Should it not be 1021?
The hole is not being treated as data, or is it? ls -l reports 1011, as does my output.
I have tried this on Mac OS X (Mojave) and linux (3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64).

Code of creating hole file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf1[] = "abcdefghij";
char buf2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

int
main (void)
{
    int fd = open ("file.hole", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0755);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror ("open() file.hole");
        exit (1);
    }

    write (fd, buf1, 10);
    lseek (fd, 1000, SEEK_SET);
    write (fd, buf2, 10);

    close (fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have 990 zero bytes, not 1000. And since SEEK_HOLE returns the end of the file it appears that your input file does not contain a hole.

Comment: You are right... I inserted 10 bytes, then lseek'd to 1000, so 990 zero bytes. Thanks :) That solves most part of the query...
But why is it being interpreted as data ? Or rather, how to make it treat as a hole using SEEK_HOLE?

Comment: What type of filesystem are you using?

Comment: xfs
$ df -T .
Filesystem              Type 1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-home xfs   43568348 40916404   2651944  94% /home

Comment: Not posted as an answer because I'm not sure - Files are stored in certain size blocks (often 4096 bytes). If there's any data in a block, then the entire block is stored.

Comment: Hey @SIddharth, almost 2 years passed, have you figured it out? Recently I ran into a problem which is kind of similar to yours. I wrote a program to print all the data and hole segments, I just use it to test on your `file.hole` and the result is there in no hole in your file.  Seems like seeking past the end of file and writing bytes possibly will not create a sparse file. If you are curious about my question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908715/list-all-the-hole-and-data-segments-in-a-sparse-file) is the link

Comment: Hi @SteveLau , no, I couldn’t figure it out. Have kept this open because I am interested still, even though I have not been actively working on anything around it. Thanks for your post, will check it out.

Comment: @Siddharth, same here, still have no idea sadly. I am watching this post, once I make some progress in the future, will leave a comment here:)